# Delay in useEffect setting the setState value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component that renders the number of people that liked the book, however I cant get consistent result in my states.

Heres my code:

```
///this is for getting the book details


  
const {id} = useParams();
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const[hasliked, sethasliked] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const bookData = {
           id: id
        }
    dispatch(openBook(bookData))   
 }, [])

///and this is for setting the state of the component

const { bookFeatured, isLoading, isSuccess, openbook, likeStatus } = useSelector(state => state.book);
const { user, isError, message } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

  useEffect(()=>{


    if(openbook.noOfLikes?.find((noOfLikes) => noOfLikes === user._id)){

      sethasliked(true)

    }else{
      sethasliked(false)
    }


},[openbook])


  const Likes = () => {
   
      return hasliked
        ? (
          <><FaHeart fontSize="small"  />&nbsp;{hasliked.toString()}</>
        ) : (
          <><FaRegHeart  fontSize="small" fill='white'/>&nbsp;{hasliked.toString()}</>
        );
  };
```

the thing here is i get inconsistent result when getting the value from const hasliked, if i already liked a book, it will sometimes tell me that the hasliked is false, but sometimes it will go to true, this caused me to get different result each time i render the component, I think it has something to do with the delay in useEffect due to async actions, Is there something that I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using setTimeout?

```
useEffect( () => {
  const tmr = setTimeout( () => { 
    const bookData = { id: id }
    dispatch( openBook(bookData) )
  }, 500)
  return () => clearTimeout(tmr);
 }, [])

useEffect( () => {
  const tmr = setTimeout( () => { 
    if (openbook.noOfLikes?.find( (noOfLikes) => noOfLikes === user._id) ) {
      sethasliked(true)
    } else { sethasliked( false) }
  }, 500)
  return () => clearTimeout(tmr);
},[openbook])
```

Comment: Hello, setting a Timeout definitely helps, I dont why this is happening but I cant seem to find any other solution for the problem so I might use this , Thankyou!

Comment: @JASMAL setTimeout will definitely work here but it isn't the standard solution bcz it will slow your application down. Because no matter how much time your request takes it will take 0.5s minimum and that is not good.

Comment: @JASMAL I have similar problem like you yesterday then try using `timeout` and voila! problem solved. I guess `useEffect` fired immediately after the component rendered even you haven't seen the component yet. anyway Your welcome!

Comment: @DharmikPatel maybe changing the interval to 0.1s will be enough, me personally set the interval to 50 still works (on my app)

Comment: @Musadarj it depends because every request takes different time so if the request won't be finished in 0.1s then he will have the same problem again.

Comment: @DharmikPatel yep, you're definitely right

Answer (score 0):

1. you are trying to render a boolean value with a `.toString()`? why not just do

```
   
      return hasliked
        ? (
          <><FaHeart fontSize="small"  />True</>
```

seeing as how `hasliked` is already true there.

---

2. this

```
else{
      sethasliked(false)
    }
```

can be eliminated by changing the init to

```
const[hasliked, sethasliked] = useState(false);
```

---

3. if your `dispatch(openBook(bookData))` is returning a promise you can set `hasliked` in a `.then` block eliminating the need for a second useeffect

---

4. change the return from this

```
return hasliked
```

to this

```
return hasliked && openbook
```

Comment: for number 1. im trying to debug if im getting the correct values from useState after setting it from useeffect, but it seems im getting inconsistent resutl from that based what is rendering from that toString function, 2.tried changing it but problem still persist(inconsistend value from hasliked) 4. tried also. but doesnt solve the problem, Im still figuring if i can use 3, but from what ive tried, i cant set the state in the then() block

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `loading state` to your component and check if the loading state is `true` then show a loader or else show your component.

```
const {id} = useParams();
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const[hasliked, sethasliked] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false) // The loading state

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true) // Setting the loading state true
    const bookData = {
           id: id
        }
    dispatch(openBook(bookData))   
 }, [])

///and this is for setting the state of the component

const { bookFeatured, isLoading, isSuccess, openbook, likeStatus } = useSelector(state => state.book);
const { user, isError, message } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

  useEffect(()=>{    
    if(openbook.noOfLikes?.find((noOfLikes) => noOfLikes === user._id)){
      sethasliked(true)
      setLoading(false) // Setting loading state to false
    }else{
      sethasliked(false)
      setLoading(false) // Setting loading state to false
    }
},[openbook])


  const Likes = () => {
      // show a loader if loading is true
      if(loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
      }   

      return hasliked
        ? (
          <><FaHeart fontSize="small"  />&nbsp;{hasliked.toString()}</>
        ) : (
          <><FaRegHeart  fontSize="small" fill='white'/>&nbsp;{hasliked.toString()}</>
        );
  };
```

Comment: tried this, im getting the same values(false) for the loading state after returning the divs, but the value of hasliked is still inconsistent. I think it has something to do with the function  if(openbook.noOfLikes?.find((noOfLikes) => noOfLikes === user._id)) , it doesnt find the noOflikes instantly, i think it needs another render before assigning the correct values for hasliked , still dont know how to fix it though

Answer (score 0):

**Recently I faced the same issue. The thing is setState() is asynchronous. Although you are setting your state variable in useEffect, it might take some take to update the state.
Solution:
Create another variable and set the value to this as well. And later compare true/false with this value.**

```
       var temp = true;
        useEffect(()=>{    
            if(openbook.noOfLikes?.find((noOfLikes) => noOfLikes === user._id)){
              sethasliked(true)
              temp = true
              setLoading(false) // Setting loading state to false
            }else{
              sethasliked(false)
              temp = false
              setLoading(false) // Setting loading state to false
            }
         }
    
    .....
    return temp
            ? (
              <><FaHeart fontSize="small"  />&nbsp;{hasliked.toString()}</>
            ) : (
              <><FaRegHeart  fontSize="small" fill='white'/>&nbsp;{hasliked.toString()}</>
            );
```